# Web Application not working after deploying on Tomcat Server 7.0.39

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

We are able to login into the application, but unable to load Header.jsp

Here is the browser exception:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /user/../layout/Header.jsp at line 36

33:     } 
34:   </style> 
35: <!--  <script type="text/javascript"> 
36:     var secondsBeforeExpire = ${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};
37:     var timeToDecide = 15; // Give client 15 seconds to choose.
38:     var initialSessionTimeoutMessage = 'Your session is about to timeout in 5 minutes.Please save your work now!';

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: it seems you have compilation error in jsp file

Comment: Please suggest some solution to go about this problem.

Comment: Please share your header.jsp

Comment: That cannot be the entire stacktrace. Check the server log file.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = ${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};
    alert (d);
</script>
```

Have you observed comment starting `<!--` in below line? Why you used `<!--` before `<script` tag?

```
<!--  <script type="text/javascript">
```